# How to return value in sequential forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

This is how I'm using a sequential forEach loop to handle some file uploads. Now I want to get a total result for each upload:
For each file I resolve with an object (success or error). At the end I want to get a returned array to display the result (File 1 successful, file 2 error and so on).

But with this code I only get `undefined` for the last output. What am I missing?

Maybe it would even be better to return two string arrays: one successful and one failed array with filenames.

```
Array.prototype.forEachSequential = async function (
    func: (item: any) => Promise<void>
): Promise<void> {
    for (let item of this) await func(item)
}
async uploadFiles(files: [File]): Promise<any> {
    const result = await files.forEachSequential(
        async (file): Promise<any> => {
        const res = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            // do some stuff
            resolve({ success: file.filename })
            // or maybe
            resolve({ error: file.filename })
        })
        console.log(res) // returns object as expected
        return res
        }
    )
    // Get all results after running forEachSequential
    console.log('result', result) // result: undefined
})
```

Comment: Your `forEachSequential` does not return anything, it only "consumes" all promises. You want to build up an array and put the results there...

Comment: @GACy20 I don't see where the `return` is missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `forEachSequential` function has no `return` statement, so it never returns anything, so calling it will always result in `undefined` (in this specific case, a promise that's fulfilled with `undefined`, since it's an `async` function). It completely ignores the return value of the callback.

You probably want a `mapSequential` (or `mapSerial`) instead, that builds an array of the results:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "mapSequential", {
    async value(func) {
        const result = [];
        for (const item of this) {
            result.push(await func(item));
        }
        return result;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
```

**Note:** I recommend you **don't** add to `Array.prototype`. Consider doing this instead:

```
async function mapSequential(iterable, func) {
    const result = [];
    for (const item of iterable) {
        result.push(await func(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

But if you do add to `Array.prototype`, be sure to do it with `defineProperty` as I did above, **not** just with assignment, and make sure the property you add isn't enumerable (either use `enumerable: false` or leave it off, `false` is the default).

You can spin this a lot of ways. You might consider a variant similar to [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) that catches errors and returns an array indicating success/failure (with or without stopping early on first error). For instance:

```
async function mapSequential(iterable, func, options) {
    const result = [];
    for (const item of iterable) {
        try {
            const value = await func(item);
            result.push({ status: "fulfilled", value });
        } catch (reason) {
            result.push({ success: "rejected", reason });
            if (options?.shortCircuit) { // Option that says "stop at first error"
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Again, though, you can spin it lots of ways. Maybe add an index and the iterable to the callback like `map` does, perhaps have an optional `thisArg` (although arrow functions make that largely unnecessary these days), etc.

Comment: *(Oops, editing error -- if you see `.call` in the above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: As it is a seqential mapping, is it possible to some progress information? As I said, I'm trying to handle some file uploads, which can of course be successful or failing. But I think it would be helpful if I can show the user 2 of 5 uploads are done. If I understand it correctly, the `mapSequential` just returns the total result at the end. So do i have a chance to get some infos out of the loop?

Comment: @user3142695 - The callback would be able to do that, since it's called on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your `forEachSequential` doesn't really return anything. That's why you get `undefined`. When awaiting, you should attach a result to some variable, store it somewhere and then at the end of this function you should return it.

Now, you would like to return a tuple `[string[], string[]]`. To do so you have to create to arrays at the beginning of `forEachSequential` body, then call `func` in the loop and add a result to first array (let's say - success array) or second (failure array).

```
const successArray = [];
const failureArray = [];

for (let item of this) {
    const result = await func(item);

    if ('success' in result) {
        successArray.push(result.success);
    } else {
        failureArray.push(result.error);
    }
}

return [successArray, failureArray];
```